# angular subscribe not waiting long enough

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component that has an a html tag with an href. I would like the value of that href to come from an angular service i have implemented and that i subscribe to but instead the href value is not coming through.
I think this is a timing issue - the page renders before the subscribe is returned. how can i remedy that?

```
<a href="{{links?.someLink1}}"> Click it </a>
```

and then in my ts i have something like:

```
    this.myService.getLinks().subscribe(linkList => {
      this.links = linkList;
console.dir(this.links); //this returns the json object so i know it is there
       });
```

if i write the html like this:

```
<a href="{{links.someLink1}}"> Click it </a>
```

i get an error about trying to read the property 'someLink1' of undefined.

***Update***

I think this has something to do with my lack of Typescript understanding. in my ts i want to declare

```
links: any;
```

but when i do that my template cannot resolve link.someLink1
If i change the ts declaration to `links ={};`
then it will work. But i don't understand why?

Comment: Try `<a href="{{links?.someLink1}}">Click it</a>`.

Comment: By stating *I think its a timing issue* I assume that you arent even sure what is causing your issue. Is `links` being correctly set? is that subscribe callback actually being called? Why dont you start by debugging your code, and adding something like `links | json` somewhere in your template in order to check that the value is set.

Comment: Please create an [mcve] and update your question with it. I recommend https://stackblitz.com

Comment: that didn't work. and if i leave out the ? i get "Cannot read property 'someLink1' of undefined". I don't think that links object is ready when the page is rendered.

Comment: i have console.logs informing me that links is being set when the sub returns

Answer (score 1):

This syntax is incorrect `<a href={{links?.someLink1}} Click it </a>`

because **>** and **"** are missing

use

```
<a href="{{links?.someLink1}}"> Click it </a>
```

or

```
<a [attr.href]="links?.someLink1"> Click it </a>
```

Also please log the data, to check if it valid url or not?

Comment: sorry that was a typo

Comment: please provide more information, unable to guess where your code is failing.

Comment: try to add some console inside of subscribe function

Comment: share the error which you are getting in console of devtools,, if any

Comment: no error in the console. I get back the object from the subscribe and i can access it in the href but only if it is declared as {} and not as any

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is that is not updating your html binding you should try to use the async pipe, btw you have to put " " after href so the result would be:

```
<a href="{{links?.someLink1 | async}}" Click it </a>
```

Comment: did you try it?